# Getting the red screen on real device with react-native

Tags: android, adb, react-native

I am using Mac OS X and an Android Phone 4.4.2

When I deploy the sample AwesomeProject app to the phone I get a Red warning screen which says "*Unable to download JS bundle. Did you forget to start the development server or connect your device?*"

However, I have started the local dev server and connected the phone to the same wifi. Moreover, when I type "*adb devices*" I can see my device.

Also I added the IP and port of the server under Dev settings.

I found an advice online to type *adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081* but my phone is not android 5.0 which is btw minimum required for dab reverse command.

How should I make it start, please help...

Answer (score 4):

Follow this steps carefully.

Note : All commands need to run inside a project only.

1. Run below command first 
    **npm react-native start**
2. open other window in same project and Run below command 
   **curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"**
3. This will create index.android.bundle in assets folder.
4. Run below command
   **npm react-native run-android**
   Now you can get apk in build folder which will work fine.